# Using calc() for width of div doesn't seem to work

Tags: html, calc

I am trying to have a text input and two buttons in the same row. The length of the text input should be maxed out so that everything still fits in a row:

```
<div style="display:flex; flex-flow:row nowrap; align-items:center; justify-content:space-between; width:100%;">
    <!-- div style='width:calc(~"100% - 150px")' -->
    <div style='width: calc(50% - 120px);'>
        <SfTextBox FloatLabelType="@FloatLabelType.Never" Placeholder='' Value=@WatermarkID() Enabled="false"></SfTextBox>
    </div>
    <div><SfButton Type="button" Content="Edit..." @onclick="EditWatermark" IsPrimary="false"></SfButton></div>
    <div><SfButton Type="button" Content="Remove..." @onclick="RemoveWatermark" IsPrimary="false"></SfButton></div>
</div>
```

This is the result (with Google Chrome):

[image: Screenshot]

If I give the div e.g. a width of 50% (style="width:50%;"), the div's width gets set as desired. The above code shows another attempt to call calc in the commented out line, which didn't work either.

What do I have to do to get the desired result (text input as long as possible with buttons to its right), and why doesn't calc seem to work here?

Comment: Just removing the `~` from the commented out one seems like the solution (If I'm understanding correctly)

Comment: Give your row's wrapper `display: flex`. then give your text input `flex: 1`. Manage the space between them with `gap`. `flex:1` means take all the space you can. So basically the other siblings take the space you give them, then all the remaining space is allocated to your input. It is equal to `flex: 1 1 100%`. `flex` is shorthand for: `flex-grow flex-shrink flex-basis` .

Comment: @DBS: Even just calc(50%) doesn't work for me. The calc(~"...") solution comes from a reply to another, related SO question I digged through before asking myself here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want both buttons pushed to the right and the input field taking up all of the available space left, you can use flexbox (what you're already using):

Remove the `justify-content: space-between` property (it's not needed anymore) and set the width of your input field to `100%`. The buttons need the property `flex-shrink: 0;` so they won't get shrinked.

Working example:

```html
<div style="display: flex; width: 100%;">
  <div style="height: 30px; background: orange; width: 100%;"></div>
  <button style="flex-shrink: 0;">Hello</button>
  <button style="flex-shrink: 0;">World</button>
</div>
```

If you want some spacing between the elements, you an use the `gap` property on the flex container, e.g. `gap: 10px;`.

Answer (score 0):

Your codes are working, just not the way you expect(text input as long as possible with buttons to its right).

Few things to get it work as you expect:

1. Remove the "justify-content:space-between;" in #d1 (text input as long as possible means no space)
2. Replace "width: calc(50% - 120px)" with "width:100%" in #d2 to make it fill the space. As you used "display:flex" in #d1, item in it will "flex", making it not occupying the whole 100% width of #d1 but shrinking a bit to achieve "as long as possible with buttons to its right"
3. Add "width:100%" to your input

```html
<div id="d1" style="display:flex; flex-flow:row nowrap; align-items:center;width:100%;">
    <div id="d2" style='width:100%;'>
        <input type='text' style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div id="d3"><button>Edit...</button></div>
    <div id="d4"><button>Remove...</button></div>
</div>
```